# How can I identify UILocalNotification and snooz it again?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am developing an alarm app and having some issues and snooz and repeatation of alarms, I am making a Class having name, time and other alarm options below

```
int alarm_id;

NSString *nameOfAlarm;
NSString *timeOfAlarm;
NSString *repeatAlarm;
NSString *soundOfAlarm;
NSString *snoozOfAlarm;
NSString *soundFadeInOfAlarm;
NSString *volumeOfAlarm;
NSString *vibrationOfAlarm;
```

Now I am saving above values to my Sqlite database, and at same time I am setting notification to iOS, when notification fires the, then I want to snooz and also want same alarm on different days, 
I don't want exact code, but a concept or view how to do that ?
Help .

Answer (score 1):

You can use UILocalNotification's userInfo to store a unique identifier for each notification.

Take a look at the UILocalNotification documentation.